# Запуск asp.net Core приложения через Powersell

Tags: asp.net-core, powershell, asp.net-core-mvc

Мне необходимо запускать asp.net Core приложение сбилденное для автономного развертывания средствами PowerShell.
При запуске через даблклик по файлу .exe приложение запускается без проблем. При вызове команды PowerShell `Start-Process "{myPath}\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\app\App.exe"` получаю ошибку:

```
An error occurred while seeding the database.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Запуск необходимо осуществлять предварительно перейдя в директорию с исполняемым файлом.